# How to embed a photo in a notification and reveal it on iphone?

Tags: ios, notifications

I tried paste a screenshot of iPhone but I don't have the reputation, so i've to describe it.

The iPhone in lock but some app reveal notifications on the screen, each one has the app's icon in the left, a message in the middle, and time by the right side. But one of them has a photo embed in the message body.

I'm curious how they implement it. If they are using Local/RemoteNotification, how to embed a photo in the alertBody?

Comment: Are you sure it is not an emoji character?

Comment: @Jerrylk Are you talking about the shared photo stream notifications? I haven't seen anything like this in any other app. I guess it is a system feature which we can observe only in the native iOS Photos app.

Comment: @cevitcejbo the app's icon is an green rectangle with a pop message inside, it may be a message app

Comment: @cevitcejbo this app should be iMessage, the photo is the previews. Only iOS native app can do this?

Comment: @Jerrylk yep, iMessage does this too. Anyway, I haven't seen this feature documented anywhere. If it were available to every app, I guess there would be a bunch of apps using it.

Comment: @cevitcejbo, thank you...actually it's glad to tell my manager I can't   do it...